# command_not_found_handler not working in mac

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, command-line

so I have this bash code in my .bashrc file...I'm using Mac OS X Yosemite

```
command_not_found_handle () 
{ 
    runcnf=1;
    retval=127;
    [ ! -S /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket ] && runcnf=0;
    [ ! -x /usr/libexec/packagekitd ] && runcnf=0;
    if [ $runcnf -eq 1 ]; then
        /usr/libexec/pk-command-not-found $@;
        retval=$?;
    else
        echo "lalalla";
        retval=1;
    fi;
    return $retval
}
```

I've used this code before in linux environment and it works just fine...whenever the user enters a bash command that doesn't exist, it would default by echoing "lalalal".....however when I use this on my Mac OS X Yosemite, it doesn't work despite the fact that my .bashrc file is properly registered (I've executed `source ~/.bash_profile` and my .bash_profile contain the code `source ~/.bashrc`

other command that exist in my .bashrc are executing just fine....

what did I do wrong and how can I make mac use command_not_found_handle whenever the user enters a command that doesn't exist in mac?

## UPDATE

@tristan so I upgraded bash via brew which is confirmed when I run `bash --version` which outputs

```
GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

moreover I redid source .bash_profile

nonetheless when I enter a command that doesnt exist it still displays

```
-bash: askldfasf: command not found
```

what did I do wrong?

Comment: Minor remark: `return $retval` is wrong: `return` only returns numeric arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`command_not_found_handle` was introduced to Bash version 4.

OS X Yosemite ships with bash-3.2 by default.

To introduce some facsimile of this, you could check the exit code of every command to look for exit code 127 ("command not found") and append a call to that function after.  You could probably patch in this behavior on your own by checking the exit code from the prior command is 127 and calling your custom `command_not_found_handle` function (using `$?` and PROMPT_COMMAND).

That said, if I was in your shoes, I'd probably upgrade Bash by installing it via [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) (`brew install bash` or from [source](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/).

e.g.

```
bash-4.3$ cat not_found.bash
command_not_found_handle()
{
        echo ":("
}
bash-4.3$ source not_found.bash
bash-4.3$ a
:(
```

I tested your script as it currently stands on my machine as well:

```
bash-4.3$ source pillar.bash
bash-4.3$ a
lalalla
```

Test `source`-ing your script interactively to make sure it's the same on your machine.

Comment: is it possible to upgrade to bash version 4? moreover is there an alternative to command_not_found_handle that can perform the same thing?

Comment: @pillarOfLight added that to my answer now.  you have options :)